# Why doesn't spatie tags syncTagsWithType store the tags submitted as an array?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, tags, tagging, laravel-tags

I'm using a react page to build a list of [spatie tags](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-tags/v4/advanced-usage/using-types) with types and then I post changes on the client side to my Laravel controller and I'm trying to run the syncTagsWithType function but it simply doesn't save; no error, the user object is returned as if it worked.

If I manually run:

```
$this->syncTagsWithType(['cinematography'], 'industry');
```

it works as expected, the tag is added and linked to the user.

Using the posted data I have to do some reformatting to get it down to a simple array, looping through my types and attempting to sync each independently.

```
   $types = ['industry', 'expertise'];
   foreach($types as $type) {
        $filteredTags = (array_filter($tags,function($a) use ($type) {
            return stripos($a['type'],$type) !== false;
        }));
        $arr = (array_column($filteredTags, 'name'));
        $this->syncTagsWithType(array_column($arr, 'en'), $type);
   }
```

I loop through the two types, filter the array of tags down to match each type, then reduce the array with array_column to just the names of the tags. I have to use array_column again to get the english name and if I dd the result with

```
dd(array_column($arr, 'en'));
```

I get:

```
array:1 [▼ // app/Models/User.php:65
  0 => "Cinematography"
]
```

Which seems like it should work, the syncTagsWithType is looking for an array and is_array confirms that I do indeed have an array. I'm stumped and any help is greatly appreciated.